# Screen stays black after closing and reopening the lid

Tags: 11.10, freeze, screen

When I close the lid or leave the computer on for a bit the screen goes black and freezes that way. I have tried changing both screen and power settings as well as changing workspaces. Nothing seems to unfreeze or wake-up the computer.

I just installed 11.10 from 11.04, never had this problem with 11.04. Was able to close and open lid just fine.

Considering reinstalling...

Help?

Comment: This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're having trouble with hibernation, which is invoked by closing (and opening) the lid. Look at `/var/log/pm-*.log`, `man pm-hibernate` and the files in the `pm-utils` package (do `dpkg -L pm-utils`). When my Ubuntu 11.10 hibernates, it also locks the screen (I think this is good). Could your system be trying to lock the screen and getting confused?

Comment: If my computer is confused, then I'm screwed. I am not the most savvy with computers so I don't know what I am looking for when looking at these files. Is there anything in particular I should be seeking out?

Comment: All of of the lines containing "Fail" and the two lines preceding them, e.g. `grep -n -B2 Fail /var/log/pm-suspend.log`. The top line of each 3-line group usually ends with "success", and can be ignored. The remaining 2 lines show the script being invoked, and the error message (containing "Fail") that `grep` found. The `-B2` says "print 2 lines before match", `-n` says "show line numbers". Don't post your whole log! But carefully read the last few 3-line groups.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing `laptop-mode-tools`, that has fixed the issue for me